# Laravel 5.2 - Session not persisting across route change

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've just installed Laravel 5.2. I'm a few hours into my project and I'm noticing the session does not persist across routes. I first noticed this when using the Validation service on a form. The `$error` variable was empty on a validation fail.

I've created two simple routes to reproduce the issue. The code is below. `Foo` route loads the session but `Bar` route does not.

- `Laravel.log` is empty.
- `sudo chmod -R 777` set on storage
- I've tried the database driver and file driver. Same outcome.
- I've updated the database to include the sessions table changes (user id, etc.)
- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan config:clear`
- When using the file driver I see the session files being stored in `storage/framework/sessions`
- I have a fresh copy of `app/Http/Kernel.php` taken from the 5.2 repository

**Routes.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {


    Route::get('foo','AuthController@foo');
    Route::get('bar','AuthController@bar');


});
```

**AuthController.php**

```
namespace Zocial\Http\Controllers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

 public function foo()
 {
  \Session::put('user','testing');

  //session( ['user' => 'testing'] ); not working either
  return \Session::get('user');
 }

 public function bar()
 {
  return "Session here: " . \Session::get('user');
 }

}
```

**Config/session.php**

```
return [

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => true,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => env('DB_CONNECTION','mysql'),
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => env('APP_DOMAIN', null),
    'secure' => false,

];
```

Comment: When using file driver do you see session files are being created inside `storage/framework/sessions` directory?

Comment: Do you installed fresh Laravel 5.2 app or made update from previous version?

Comment: Could you please make sure you have valid `app/Http/Kernel.php` file structure? Default one is here https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php

Comment: Any solution for this problem? I'm facing the same one.

Comment: I created a new Laravel 5.2 product from scratch and copied module by module over to the new project and now have a replicated project with working sessions. I never did figure out the root cause.

Comment: Did you generate a `app_key`? I had a similar problem until I generated the key: `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: you should remove the web middleware, it's standard for all routes in web.php now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
public function foo(Request $request)
{
    $value = $request->session()->put('key', 'value');

}

public function bar(Request $request)
{
    $value = $request->session()->get('key');
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Sure. I believe your first method should be `foo`. So I have updated your code to that. I get the same results as in my example. The session is not getting returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default Auth that is included in 5.2, then try to do this:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

This will recreate your auth controller and everything else that comes with the standard auth that laravel 5.2 includes.

This was the only thing that helped me. (It stopped working after I set the sessions to Database...)

---

Update 1

Apparently it logs you out of the application and gives you a token mismatch when you have a route defined in your routes.php that utilizes the "web" middleware.

Like this: (watch out code below NOT working)

```
Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');


Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```

Going to the root of your website logs you out, when you to to /home again, you are redirected to the login. If you try to login again, it gives you a token mismatch.

The following stopped the error from appearing:

```
Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Either I do not understand the new middleware stuff, OR its not working, since my Route for "/" should use the web middleware or am I wrong?

---

Solution:
You need to remove the web middleware from your route / route groups, since the web middleware is being added automatically since 5.2, thats what has been causeing the problem for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed sessions do not persist if 'secure' is set to true under config/session.php and you are not accessing your site through HTTPS. I solved this by setting 'secure' to false.